Error in load_function when Deploying Azure Function Locally for Testing
I'm encountering an issue while trying to deploy an Azure Function locally for testing. The error message I'm receiving is as follows:
[2024-08-08T14:31:02.558Z] Error in load_function. Sys Path: ['C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64', 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64', 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\miniconda3\\python310.zip', 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\miniconda3\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\miniconda3\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\miniconda3', 'C:\\Users\\username\\azfunc-autoitp-preprocess-v3\\.venv', in)>, 'bisect': <module 'bisect' from 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\miniconda3\\lib\\bisect.py'>, '_random': <module '_random' (built-in)>, '_sha512': <module '_sha512' (built-in)>, 'random': <module 'random' from 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\miniconda3\\lib\\random.py'>, 'tempfile': <module 'tempfile' from 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\miniconda3\\lib\\tempfile.py'>, 'asyncio.windows_utils': <module 'asyncio.windows_utils' from 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\miniconda3\\lib\\asyncio\\windows_utils.py'>, 'asyncio.windows_events': <module 'asyncio.windows_events' from 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\miniconda3\\lib\\asyncio\\windows_events.py'>, 'asyncio': <module 'asyncio' from 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\miniconda3\\lib\\asyncio\\__init__.py'>, 'azure_functions_worker._thirdparty.aio_compat': <module 'azure_functions_worker._thirdparty.aio_compat' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\azure_functions_worker\\_thirdparty\\aio_compat.py'>, 'locale': <module 'locale' from 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\miniconda3\\lib\\locale.py'>, 'azure_functions_worker.dispatcher': <module 'azure_functions_worker.dispatcher' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\azure_functions_worker\\dispatcher.py'>, 'platform': <module 'platform' 
from 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\miniconda3\\lib\\platform.py'>, 'grpc._cython': <module 'grpc._cython' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\grpc\\_cython\\__init__.py'>, '_cython_0_29_25': <module '_cython_0_29_25'>, 'cython_runtime': <module 'cython_runtime'>, 'importlib._abc': <module 'importlib._abc' from 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\miniconda3\\lib\\importlib\\_abc.py'>, 'importlib.util': <module 'importlib.util' from 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\miniconda3\\lib\\importlib\\util.py'>, 'pkgutil': <module 'pkgutil' from 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\miniconda3\\lib\\pkgutil.py'>, 'grpc._cython.cygrpc': <module 'grpc._cython.cygrpc' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\grpc\\_cython\\cygrpc.cp310-win_amd64.pyd'>, 'grpc._compression': <module 'grpc._compression' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\grpc\\_compression.py'>, 'grpc._runtime_protos': <module 'grpc._runtime_protos' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\grpc\\_runtime_protos.py'>, '__future__': <module '__future__' from 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\miniconda3\\lib\\__future__.py'>, 'six': <module 'six' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\six.py'>, 'grpc._grpcio_metadata': <module 'grpc._grpcio_metadata' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\grpc\\_grpcio_metadata.py'>, 'grpc_tools': <module 'grpc_tools' from 'C:\\Users\\username\\azfunc-autoitp-preprocess-v3\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\grpc_tools\\__init__.py'>, 'grpc.tools': <module 'grpc_tools' from 'C:\\Users\\username\\azfunc-autoitp-preprocess-v3\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\grpc_tools\\__init__.py'>, 'grpc_health': <module 'grpc_health' from 'C:\\Users\\username\\azfunc-autoitp-preprocess-v3\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\grpc_health\\__init__.py'>, 'grpc.health': <module 'grpc_health' from 'C:\\Users\\username\\azfunc-autoitp-preprocess-v3\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\grpc_health\\__init__.py'>, 'grpc.aio._metadata': <module 'grpc.aio._metadata' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\grpc\\aio\\_metadata.py'>, 'grpc.aio._typing': <module 'grpc.aio._typing' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\grpc\\aio\\_typing.py'>, 'grpc.aio._base_call': <module 'grpc.aio._base_call' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\grpc\\aio\\_base_call.py'>, 'grpc.aio._base_channel': <module 'grpc.aio._base_channel' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\grpc\\aio\\_base_channel.py'>, 'grpc.aio._base_server': <module 'grpc.aio._base_server' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\grpc\\aio\\_base_server.py'>, 'grpc._common': <module 'grpc._common' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\grpc\\_common.py'>, 'grpc.aio._call': <module 'grpc.aio._call' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\grpc\\aio\\_call.py'>, 'grpc.aio._utils': <module 'grpc.aio._utils' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\grpc\\aio\\_utils.py'>, 'grpc.aio._interceptor': <module 'grpc.aio._interceptor' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\grpc\\aio\\_interceptor.py'>, 'grpc.aio._channel': <module 'grpc.aio._channel' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\grpc\\aio\\_channel.py'>, 'grpc.aio._server': <module 'grpc.aio._server' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\grpc\\aio\\_server.py'>, 'grpc.aio': <module 'grpc.aio' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\grpc\\aio\\__init__.py'>, 'grpc': <module 'grpc' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\grpc\\__init__.py'>, 'azure_functions_worker.bindings.tracecontext': <module 
'azure_functions_worker.bindings.tracecontext' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\azure_functions_worker\\bindings\\tracecontext.py'>, 'azure_functions_worker.bindings.rpcexception': <module 'azure_functions_worker.bindings.rpcexception' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\azure_functions_worker\\bindings\\rpcexception.py'>, 'azure_functions_worker.bindings.retrycontext': <module 'azure_functions_worker.bindings.retrycontext' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\azure_functions_worker\\bindings\\retrycontext.py'>, 'azure_functions_worker.bindings.context': <module 'azure_functions_worker.bindings.context' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\azure_functions_worker\\bindings\\context.py'>, 'google': <module 'google' (<_frozen_importlib_external._NamespaceLoader object at 0x000001FD835D41F0>)>, 'google.protobuf': <module 'google.protobuf' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\google\\protobuf\\__init__.py'>, 'google.protobuf.internal': <module 'google.protobuf.internal' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\google\\protobuf\\internal\\__init__.py'>, 'google.protobuf.internal.enum_type_wrapper': <module 'google.protobuf.internal.enum_type_wrapper' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\google\\protobuf\\internal\\enum_type_wrapper.py'>, 'google.protobuf.internal._api_implementation': <module 'google.protobuf.internal._api_implementation' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\google\\protobuf\\internal\\_api_implementation.cp310-win_amd64.pyd'>, 'google.protobuf.internal.api_implementation': <module 'google.protobuf.internal.api_implementation' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\google\\protobuf\\internal\\api_implementation.py'>, 'google.protobuf.pyext': <module 'google.protobuf.pyext' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\google\\protobuf\\pyext\\__init__.py'>, 'google.protobuf.message': <module 'google.protobuf.message' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\google\\protobuf\\message.py'>, 'google.protobuf.pyext._message': <module 'google.protobuf.pyext._message' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\google\\protobuf\\pyext\\_message.cp310-win_amd64.pyd'>, 'google.protobuf.descriptor': <module 'google.protobuf.descriptor' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\google\\protobuf\\descriptor.py'>, 'google.protobuf.descriptor_database': <module 'google.protobuf.descriptor_database' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\google\\protobuf\\descriptor_database.py'>, 'google.protobuf.text_encoding': <module 'google.protobuf.text_encoding' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\google\\protobuf\\text_encoding.py'>, 'google.protobuf.descriptor_pool': <module 'google.protobuf.descriptor_pool' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\google\\protobuf\\descriptor_pool.py'>, 'google.protobuf.pyext.cpp_message': <module 'google.protobuf.pyext.cpp_message' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\google\\protobuf\\pyext\\cpp_message.py'>, 'google.protobuf.message_factory': <module 'google.protobuf.message_factory' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\google\\protobuf\\message_factory.py'>, 'google.protobuf.symbol_database': <module 'google.protobuf.symbol_database' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\google\\protobuf\\symbol_database.py'>, 'google.protobuf.reflection': <module 'google.protobuf.reflection' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\google\\protobuf\\reflection.py'>, '_datetime': <module '_datetime' (built-in)>, 'datetime': <module 'datetime' from 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\miniconda3\\lib\\datetime.py'>, 'calendar': <module 'calendar' from 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\miniconda3\\lib\\calendar.py'>, 'google.protobuf.internal.well_known_types': <module 'google.protobuf.internal.well_known_types' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\google\\protobuf\\internal\\well_known_types.py'>, 'google.protobuf.duration_pb2': <module 'google.protobuf.duration_pb2' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\google\\protobuf\\duration_pb2.py'>, 'azure_functions_worker.protos.identity': <module 'azure_functions_worker.protos.identity' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\azure_functions_worker\\protos\\identity\\__init__.py'>, 'azure_functions_worker.protos.shared': <module 'azure_functions_worker.protos.shared' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\azure_functions_worker\\protos\\shared\\__init__.py'>, 'google.protobuf.timestamp_pb2': <module 'google.protobuf.timestamp_pb2' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\google\\protobuf\\timestamp_pb2.py'>, 'azure_functions_worker.protos.shared.NullableTypes_pb2': <module 'azure_functions_worker.protos.shared.NullableTypes_pb2' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\azure_functions_worker\\protos\\shared\\NullableTypes_pb2.py'>, 'azure_functions_worker.protos.identity.ClaimsIdentityRpc_pb2': <module 'azure_functions_worker.protos.identity.ClaimsIdentityRpc_pb2' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\azure_functions_worker\\protos\\identity\\ClaimsIdentityRpc_pb2.py'>, 'azure_functions_worker.protos.FunctionRpc_pb2': <module 'azure_functions_worker.protos.FunctionRpc_pb2' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\azure_functions_worker\\protos\\FunctionRpc_pb2.py'>, 'azure_functions_worker.protos.FunctionRpc_pb2_grpc': <module 'azure_functions_worker.protos.FunctionRpc_pb2_grpc' 
from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\azure_functions_worker\\protos\\FunctionRpc_pb2_grpc.py'>, 'azure_functions_worker.protos': <module 'azure_functions_worker.protos' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\azure_functions_worker\\protos\\__init__.py'>, '_json': <module '_json' (built-in)>, 'json.scanner': <module 'json.scanner' from 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\miniconda3\\lib\\json\\scanner.py'>, 'json.decoder': <module 'json.decoder' from 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\miniconda3\\lib\\json\\decoder.py'>, 'json.encoder': <module 'json.encoder' from 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\miniconda3\\lib\\json\\encoder.py'>, 'json': <module 'json' from 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\miniconda3\\lib\\json\\__init__.py'>, 'http': <module 'http' from 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\miniconda3\\lib\\http\\__init__.py'>, 'http.cookies': <module 'http.cookies' from 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\miniconda3\\lib\\http\\cookies.py'>, 'dateutil._version': <module 'dateutil._version' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\dateutil\\_version.py'>, 'dateutil': <module 'dateutil' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\dateutil\\__init__.py'>, 'numbers': <module 'numbers' from 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\miniconda3\\lib\\numbers.py'>, '_decimal': <module '_decimal' from 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\miniconda3\\DLLs\\_decimal.pyd'>, 'decimal': <module 'decimal' from 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\miniconda3\\lib\\decimal.py'>, 'dateutil._common': <module 'dateutil._common' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\dateutil\\_common.py'>, 'dateutil.relativedelta': <module 'dateutil.relativedelta' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\dateutil\\relativedelta.py'>, 'six.moves': <module 'six.moves' (<six._SixMetaPathImporter object at 0x000001FD835041C0>)>, 'dateutil.tz._common': <module 'dateutil.tz._common' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\dateutil\\tz\\_common.py'>, 'dateutil.tz._factories': <module 'dateutil.tz._factories' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\dateutil\\tz\\_factories.py'>, '_ctypes': <module '_ctypes' from 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\miniconda3\\DLLs\\_ctypes.pyd'>, 'ctypes._endian': <module 'ctypes._endian' from 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\miniconda3\\lib\\ctypes\\_endian.py'>, 'ctypes': <module 'ctypes' from 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\miniconda3\\lib\\ctypes\\__init__.py'>, 'ctypes.wintypes': <module 'ctypes.wintypes' from 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\miniconda3\\lib\\ctypes\\wintypes.py'>, 'dateutil.tz.win': <module 'dateutil.tz.win' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\dateutil\\tz\\win.py'>, 'dateutil.tz.tz': <module 'dateutil.tz.tz' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\dateutil\\tz\\tz.py'>, 'dateutil.tz': <module 'dateutil.tz' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\dateutil\\tz\\__init__.py'>, 'dateutil.parser._parser': <module 'dateutil.parser._parser' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\dateutil\\parser\\_parser.py'>, 'dateutil.parser.isoparser': <module 'dateutil.parser.isoparser' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\dateutil\\parser\\isoparser.py'>, 'dateutil.parser': <module 'dateutil.parser' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\dateutil\\parser\\__init__.py'>, 'azure_functions_worker.bindings.nullable_converters': <module 'azure_functions_worker.bindings.nullable_converters' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\azure_functions_worker\\bindings\\nullable_converters.py'>, 'azure_functions_worker.bindings.datumdef': <module 'azure_functions_worker.bindings.datumdef' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\azure_functions_worker\\bindings\\datumdef.py'>, 'azure_functions_worker.bindings.generic': <module 'azure_functions_worker.bindings.generic' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\azure_functions_worker\\bindings\\generic.py'>, 'mmap': <module 'mmap' (built-in)>, 'azure_functions_worker.bindings.shared_memory_data_transfer.shared_memory_constants': <module 'azure_functions_worker.bindings.shared_memory_data_transfer.shared_memory_constants' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\azure_functions_worker\\bindings\\shared_memory_data_transfer\\shared_memory_constants.py'>, 'azure_functions_worker.bindings.shared_memory_data_transfer.file_accessor': <module 'azure_functions_worker.bindings.shared_memory_data_transfer.file_accessor' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\azure_functions_worker\\bindings\\shared_memory_data_transfer\\file_accessor.py'>, 'azure_functions_worker.bindings.shared_memory_data_transfer.shared_memory_exception': <module 'azure_functions_worker.bindings.shared_memory_data_transfer.shared_memory_exception' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\azure_functions_worker\\bindings\\shared_memory_data_transfer\\shared_memory_exception.py'>, 'azure_functions_worker.bindings.shared_memory_data_transfer.file_accessor_unix': <module 'azure_functions_worker.bindings.shared_memory_data_transfer.file_accessor_unix' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\azure_functions_worker\\bindings\\shared_memory_data_transfer\\file_accessor_unix.py'>, 'azure_functions_worker.bindings.shared_memory_data_transfer.file_accessor_windows': <module 'azure_functions_worker.bindings.shared_memory_data_transfer.file_accessor_windows' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\azure_functions_worker\\bindings\\shared_memory_data_transfer\\file_accessor_windows.py'>, 'azure_functions_worker.bindings.shared_memory_data_transfer.file_accessor_factory': <module 'azure_functions_worker.bindings.shared_memory_data_transfer.file_accessor_factory' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\azure_functions_worker\\bindings\\shared_memory_data_transfer\\file_accessor_factory.py'>, 'azure_functions_worker.bindings.shared_memory_data_transfer.shared_memory_map': <module 'azure_functions_worker.bindings.shared_memory_data_transfer.shared_memory_map' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\azure_functions_worker\\bindings\\shared_memory_data_transfer\\shared_memory_map.py'>, '_uuid': <module '_uuid' from 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\miniconda3\\DLLs\\_uuid.pyd'>, 'uuid': <module 'uuid' from 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\miniconda3\\lib\\uuid.py'>, 'azure_functions_worker.bindings.shared_memory_data_transfer.shared_memory_metadata': <module 'azure_functions_worker.bindings.shared_memory_data_transfer.shared_memory_metadata' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\azure_functions_worker\\bindings\\shared_memory_data_transfer\\shared_memory_metadata.py'>, 'azure_functions_worker.bindings.shared_memory_data_transfer.shared_memory_manager': <module 'azure_functions_worker.bindings.shared_memory_data_transfer.shared_memory_manager' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\azure_functions_worker\\bindings\\shared_memory_data_transfer\\shared_memory_manager.py'>, 'azure_functions_worker.bindings.shared_memory_data_transfer': <module 'azure_functions_worker.bindings.shared_memory_data_transfer' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\azure_functions_worker\\bindings\\shared_memory_data_transfer\\__init__.py'>, 'azure_functions_worker.bindings.meta': <module 'azure_functions_worker.bindings.meta' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\azure_functions_worker\\bindings\\meta.py'>, 'azure_functions_worker.bindings.out': <module 'azure_functions_worker.bindings.out' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\azure_functions_worker\\bindings\\out.py'>, 'azure_functions_worker.bindings': <module 'azure_functions_worker.bindings' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\azure_functions_worker\\bindings\\__init__.py'>, 'azure_functions_worker._thirdparty.typing_inspect': <module 'azure_functions_worker._thirdparty.typing_inspect' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\azure_functions_worker\\_thirdparty\\typing_inspect.py'>, 'azure_functions_worker.functions': <module 'azure_functions_worker.functions' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\azure_functions_worker\\functions.py'>, 'azure_functions_worker.loader': <module 'azure_functions_worker.loader' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\azure-functions-core-tools\\tools\\workers\\python\\3.10\\WINDOWS\\X64\\azure_functions_worker\\loader.py'>},python-packages Path exists: False

I was expecting to be able to run the azure function locally. I have a collegue that was able to run it on their machine, which leads me to believe it is an issue with my local environmental set up.
However i have tried creating different .envs and updating the paths to python exe etc but none of these have worked

This error throws when function environment  configuration is not correct and module imports not working.
To execute function steps are:

Make sure python paths is set in in environment variable in user variables in Path variable

C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\



Create a virtual environment using this comand and activate it

python -m venv .venv        #   creates .venv virtual environment 
.venv/Scripts/activate      # activates the .venv environmentt



Install modules or packages which is required in project using command pip install -r requirements.txt
Then run command func host start to execute the function.

OUTPUT:


